# Displaying Microsoft project document in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ms-project

Is there a way to display Microsoft project documents in a OOTB sharepoint web part in a similar fashion to how Excel Files can be displayed using the OOTB "Excel web access" web part?

If not, what are the other effective methods in acheiving the same?

Custom list with column groupings (Expand Collapse absed on dates, project titles) perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Project Web App. It is part of Microsoft Project Server but can harness SharePoint 2010 to view Project documents as well as creating, editing and managing projects, along with most of the bells and whistles Microsoft Project gives you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197479

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-server-help/getting-started-with-project-web-app-HA010379908.aspx

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking for ways to do it sans MIcrosoft Project. I understand the 3rd party tool-project publisher does a good job at just that.